# No funcionan mis restricciones CHECK

Tags: sql

Intento hacer que la ID_GENERAL tenga el formato restringido "CL000000", sin embargo, al intentar insertarlo de esta manera me lo impide.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONA
(ID_GENERAL CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,    
CURP CHAR(18), 
NOMBRE CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO_PAT CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO_MAT CHAR(20),
EDAD SMALLINT CHECK(EDAD>=18),
PAIS CHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
PASAPORTE INT,
DIRECCION CHAR(45) NOT NULL,
TELEFONO INT NOT NULL,
CORREO VARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE PERSONA
ADD CONSTRAINT CD321845
CHECK(ID_GENERAL LIKE 'CL[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')

INSERT INTO PERSONA(ID_GENERAL,CURP,NOMBRE,APELLIDO_PAT,APELLIDO_MAT,EDAD,PAIS,DIRECCION,TELEFONO,CORREO)
VALUES ('CL173021','AECS050896HMCLLQ02', 'NORBERTO', 'PAZ','RUIZ',25,'MEXICO','AV REVOLUCION', 55246821, 'perro_callejero@gmail.com')
```

No se si sea un error de nomenclatura o yo no sé, per la verdad no entiendo que pasa.

Comment: El código que presentas es correcto. Si intentas insertar una persona cuyo id_general no encaja en que inicie por CL y luego contenga 6 números te da un error de restricción CD321845. ¿Porque dices que no funciona? ¿Cuál es el error explicito?